# select part of filename using regex

Tags: regex, text, sed, unix

I got a file that looks like

```
dcdd62defb908e37ad037820f7  /sp/dir/su1/89/asga.gz
7d59319afca23b02f572a4034b  /sp/dir/su2/89/sfdh.gz
ee1d443b8a0cc27749f4b31e56  /sp/dir/su3/89/24.gz
33c02e311fd0a894f7f0f8aae4  /sp/dir/su4/89/dfad.gz
43f6cdce067f6794ec378c4e2a  /sp/dir/su5/89/adf.gz
2f6c584116c567b0f26dfc8703  /sp/dir/su6/895/895.gz
a864b7e327dac1bb6de59dedce  /sp/dir/su7/895/895.gz
```

How do i use sed to substitue all the su* such that I can replace with a single value like

```
sed "s/REXEXP/newfolder/g" myfile
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want the "output" to be?  Do you have to use `sed`? Finally, are the directories starting with `su` always going to be of the form `su[0-9]`? `su[0-9]*`? Do you want to get rid of the md5 sums too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
sed 's/su./newfolder/g'
```

If you actually want to keep the number in `su1`...`su7` as a part of `newfolder` (for example `newfolder1`...`newfolder7`), you can do:

```
sed 's/su\(.\)/newfolder\1/g'
```

It also depends upon how "strict" do you want your patterns to be.  The above will match `su` followed by any character and do the replacement.  On the other hand, a command like `s#/su\([0-9]\)/#/newfolder\1/#g` will only match `/su` followed by a digit, followed by `/`.  So you may need to adjust your pattern accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e 's|/su[^/]*|/newfolder|' /tmp/files\
dcdd62defb908e37ad037820f7  /sp/dir/newfolder/89/asga.gz
7d59319afca23b02f572a4034b  /sp/dir/newfolder/89/sfdh.gz
...
```

If you want to get rid of the checksums as well:

```
$ sed -r -e 's|/su[^/]*|/newfolder|' -e 's/^[^ ]+ +//' /tmp/files\
/sp/dir/newfolder/89/asga.gz
/sp/dir/newfolder/89/sfdh.gz
...
```

Comment: As I said in my other comment, you don't need `/` to be the delimiter for `s`, so you can write: `sed -e 's#/su[^/]*#/newfolder#'  /tmp/files` for more readability.

Comment: what if one of the directory looks like /sp/su4dir/su1/89/24.gz ?

Comment: @ghostdog74: the problem is not very well-defined, so we can only guess about what pattern the OP really needs.

Answer (score 0):

`su[0-9]` will match a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

sed requires a dirty amount of metacharacter escaping, some of it may be slightly off.

```
sed -i -e 's/\/su[^\/]+\//\/newFolder\//g' myfile
```

Comment: You don't need `/` to be the character after `s`, so you can pick any character not in your pattern: so, `'sxsu[^/]+/x/newFolder/xg'` does the same (if I didn't make a typo).

Comment: @Alok: Thanks for the tip, i always knew that was possible in perl, didn't reaise you should do it in SED, very useful, since escapes make sed regex near unreadable!

Comment: it works when i changed + to .*. also, it doesn't take care of paths like : /sp/su4dir/su1/89/24.gz

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Wayne Conrad's answer as the most likely to be what the OP wants, but I'd suggest using an alternate character for the sed expression separator, thus:

```
sed 's|/su[^/]*|/newfolder|'  /tmp/files
```

That makes it a bit cleaner.

Note also that the trailing 'g' is probably not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

use awk. since there is a delimiter you can use , '/'. after that, column 4 is what you want to change. So if you have paths like /sp/su3dir/su2/89/sfdh.gz , su3dir will not be affected.

```
awk -F"/" '{$4="newfolder";}1' OFS="/" file
```